# $P_2$ is always an induced subgraph of a graph with at least one edge?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can I say that $P_2$ is always an induced subgraph of a graph with at least one edge? I'm trying to prove that the second largest eigenvalue of adjacency matrix is $\geq -1$, i. e., $\lambda_2(G) \geq -1$. If this is valid, I can use interlacing theorem to conclude. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can say that provided graph is simple!

Comment: Oh right! Thank you so much!